# Openlayers Styling WMS with SLD from external file problem

Tags: styles, openlayers, geoserver, wms, sld

I am facing with problem how to use style in SLD format to styling WMS from geoserver. I would like to add SLD definition as variable ${sld} from external .js file:

```
const sld = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">

   <sld:UserLayer>

     ...  


            <sld:ColorMap type="ramp">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="0"  label ="0" color="#000000"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1200" label="1200" color="#d7191c"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
     ...
   
  </sld:UserLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>



export default sld
```

The code in main.js is:

```
import sld from "./SLD_styles/style1"

...

const wmsSource2 = new TileWMS({
    url: "https://...",
    params: {
        LAYERS: "workSpace:layerName",
                STYLES: undefined,
        SLD_BODY: encodeURIComponent(sld),
    },
    serverType: "geoserver",
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
})
```

I've tried so many ways to achive that but without success. Can someone halp me how exactly SLD should look like? Probably I have problem with matching names, isDefault parameter and so.

Thanks,
Piotr

Import sld variable works fine. I have tried to import from .sld file using SLD: url, with out success as well.

Answer (score 1):

Checked "external styles" and "library mode" (part of the SLD spec) in the GeoServer documentation:

https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#external-styles

In particular, your style is likely not being used because you're in library mode:

- The SLD must use a NamedLayer matching the same name used in the LAYERS paramer
- The UserStyle must match the same name used in the STYLES (or skip using STYLES, and mark the style as default in the SLD)

Here is a working example using the style name in the URL:

https://gs-main.geosolutionsgroup.com/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp%3Astates&bbox=-124.73142200000001%2C24.955967%2C-66.969849%2C49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=popgray&format=application/openlayers&sld=https://gs-main.geosolutionsgroup.com/geoserver/styles/popgray.sld

Comment: thanks,

I do not know why, but it still doesn't work for me...
I've add matching Name and isDefault value as 1. Can you write working example? What should the structure look like in sld and coresponding wms params?